# passing php array to script via jquery.get()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

in my script, i have this line..

```
$scope.items = [{"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}];
```

i made a data.php file to simulate the array value of $scope.items shown above

```
<?php
getaccessories = array("id"=>"1","name"=>"name 1","description"=>"description 1","field3"=>"field3 1","field4"=>"field4 1","field5 "=>"field5 1");

echo json_encode($getaccessories);
?>
```

the idea is to receive this array from data.php to $scope.items in my script via jquery.get(). i tried below statement with no result. how will it be done?

```
$scope.items = $.get("data.php", function(data){}, "json");
```

@sergiu, here's what you have asked me to do for data.php, please see if i did it right?

```
<?php

// $getaccessories = array("id"=>"1","name"=>"name 1","description"=>"description 1","field3"=>"field3 1","field4"=>"field4 1","field5 "=>"field5 1");

$getaccessories = array();
$accessory = new stdClass();
$accessory->id = "1";
$accessory->name = "name 1";
$accessory->description = "description 1";
$accessory->field3 = "field3 1";
$accessory->field4 = "field4 1";
$accessory->field5 = "field5 1";

$getaccessories[] = $accessory;


echo json_encode($getaccessories);
?>
```

------ EDIT for Sergiu ------

this is the output of chrome's console.log with the original value of $scope.items

```
[Object]
0: Object
        age: 50
        name: "Moroni"
  __proto__: Object
  length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

and here's $scope.items with $.get()

```
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
    $$v: Array[1]
        0: Object
            age: 50
            name: "Moroni"
        __proto__: Object
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array[0]
```

i'm hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You probably need

```
$.get("data.php", function(data){
    $scope.items = data;
}, "json");
```

Second argument to $.get is the callback, as in call it back for me when you receive the data I requested from the server.

I'm also guessing you have that `$` in front of `getaccessories`.

You are expecting an array of objects.
You can build it like this:

```
$getaccessories = array();
$accessory = new stdClass();
$accessory->id = "1";
$accessory->name = ="name 1";
...

$getaccessories[] = $accessory;
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried your solution and it received nothing. perhaps json_encode($getaccessories) doesn't have the correct array composition for $scope.items to received?

Comment: See my updated answer. You are probably not building it correctly.

Comment: k tnx, gonna try it now...

Comment: didn't work. kindly check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/895/ the idea to have an array coming from data.php for $scope.items

Comment: I don't see any issues with your client-side AngularJS code. Debug and find out if `json_encode($getaccessories)` looks like what `$scope.items` should look.

Comment: yeah, perhaps the problem is data.php... i will check on it

Comment: just to be sure, i have updated my question and included your version of data.php as you have instructed. kindly check.

Comment: Seems to be working OK: http://ideone.com/hJgfvs

Comment: i have this error in my chrome console.. ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: $.get is from jQuery. Did you include it?

Comment: yes sir.. jquery.min.js... i made a fiddle just to check the array output. the comparison result between the original and with jQuery.get()version is remarkably different.. http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/2796/  so its either how data.php constructed the return array or the composition of jQuery.get()

Comment: i have edited my question with console.log comparison result. please have a look.